# Use of java.lang.Comparable,when the java.util.Comparator can do the work of Comparable?

Tags: java

Employee ID **sort** can be done using **Comparable** also as well as **Comparator** also but Why we go for **Comparable** when it comes to ID Sorting and why we go for **Comparator** when it comes to Name's sorting etc...?? Why can't we use Only **Comparator** for all the work???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Comparable` is usually used to define a natural ordering (or you can call it a default ordering) on the instances of the class in which it is implemented.

In your `Employee` example (which is not detailed enough), I can assume that the employee ID is a unique identifier that identifies each employee, so it makes a good candidate for use in the definition of the natural ordering.

The `Comparator` interface allows us to implement additional orderings on instances of the `Employee` class, such as ordering by name, age, etc...

You could use just `Comparator`, but whenever a class has a natural ordering, it makes sense to implement `Comparable`, which allows you to use some classes and methods that require ordering (`TreeSet`, `Collections.sort()`, etc...) without having to pass a `Comparator` instance.

Comment: "which allows you to use some classes and methods that require ordering (TreeSet, Collections.sort(), etc...) without having to pass a Comparator instance" This answer satisfies the question. Thank you:)

Answer (score 3):

If you want, you *can* use `Comparator` only. It allows you to freely define arbitrary ways to order object instances (independent of the object's own implementation).

The idea behind `Comparable` is that there may be a "natural" way to compare instances of some classes. For example, `String` can be compared to other `String`s (to get lexicographical ordering). The class can then "advertise" this natural ordering and make it conveniently accessible.

I don't know if it makes sense for your `Employee` class to declare ID ordering "natural". Either way, you can only "promote" one order to be the natural one (and it cannot be changed without changing the implementation and contract of the class, so choose wisely).